# Run two machine learning trainings in parallel in Dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have Dask distributed implemented with workers on Docker. I start 10 workers with a Docker compose file like so:

```
 docker-compose up -d --scale worker=10
```

To run a machine learning training of two models I do the following:

```
y1 = data1[label1]
X1 = data1[features1] 

y2 = data2[label2]
X2 = data2[features2] 

with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
        try:
            model1.fit(X1, y1)
            model2.fit(X2, y2)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('There's an error ' + str(e))
```

Now, I want to run in parallel the two trainings. I could use worker 1 to 5 for training 1 and worker 6 to 10 for training 2. But how to tell Dask distributed to use some workers for one task and other workers for a different task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is relatively high-level, but I'll offer some suggestions that might be of use.

To begin with, your code as written runs most things locally. To execute ML training in parallel you'll want to:

1. Work on a cluster (locally or remote).
2. Store data in Dask arrays or dataframes
3. Use  `dask.delayed` tasks

OR

4. Use the `client.submit()` API

**1. Create a (Local) Cluster**

From your code it's not clear whether you've instantiated a client, so perhaps just double-check that you're following [the dask-ml docs instructions](https://ml.dask.org/joblib.html#scikit-learn-joblib) here:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
import joblib

client = Client(processes=False)        # create local cluster
# import coiled                         # or connect to remote cluster
# client = Client(coiled.Cluster())     

with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    # your scikit-learn code
```

However, note that the Dask joblib backend to scitkit-learn is useful for scaling out CPU-bound workloads. To scale out to RAM-bound workloads (larger-than-memory datasets) you'll want to consider using one of the `dask-ml` parallel estimators, such as suggested below.

**2. Storing Data in Dask Arrays**

The minimal code example below sets up two dummy datasets as Dask arrays and instantiates a K-Means clustering algorithm.

```py
import dask_ml.datasets
import dask_ml.cluster
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dummy datasets
X, y = dask_ml.datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=10000000,
                                   chunks=1000000,
                                   random_state=0,
                                   centers=3)

X2, y2 = dask_ml.datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=10000000,
                                   chunks=1000000,
                                   random_state=3,
                                   centers=3)

# persist predictor sets to cluster memory
X = X.persist()
X2 = X2.persist()

# instantiate KM model
km = dask_ml.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3, init_max_iter=2, oversampling_factor=10)
```

**3. Training in Parallel with Dask.Delayed**

The code below runs the training in parallel using the `dask.delayed` API. It follows [the best practices outlined in the Dask docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed-best-practices.html).

```py
from dask import delayed
import dask

X = delayed(X)
X2 = delayed(X2)

@delayed
def train(model, X):
    return model.fit(X)

# define task graphs (lazy evaluation, no computation triggered)
km1 = train(km, X)
km2 = train(km, X2)

# trigger computation and yield fitted models in parallel
km1, km2 = dask.compute(km1, km2)
```

**4. Training in Parallel with Futures and `client.submit`**

Alternatively, you can train in parallel using the `client.submit()` API. This immediately returns a future that points to the ongoing computation, and eventually to the stored result. Read more in [the docs here](https://examples.dask.org/futures.html?).

*Based on your question formulation, I've assumed that your main priority here is to have the training run in parallel. This doesn't require manually assigning tasks to specific workers; Dask takes care of the scheduling and optimal distribution across workers for you. In case you are actually interested in manually assigning specific tasks to specific workers, I'd suggest taking a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068298/is-it-possible-to-select-workers-for-specific-tasks-in-dask).*

Comment: Yes, the main objective is to have the training run in parallel and I'm fine with Dask assigning the tasks to the workers. I have a big Pandas dataframe to train, should I convert it to Dask dataframe before training, so it is distributed through the workers, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @ps0604 yes, you'll absolutely want to convert your pandas dataframe to a dask dataframe with dask.dataframe.from_pandas(pandas_df). see here https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.from_pandas.html?highlight=from_pandas